# If $f(x)=\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^4}4+x^3+\frac{kx^2}2+x$ is a real valued function, find maximum $k^2$ if $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x \in R$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

> If $f(x)=\frac{x^5}5+\frac{x^4}4+x^3+\frac{kx^2}2+x$ be a real valued function. Find the maximum value of $k^2$ for which $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x \in R$.

I differentiated the function, and set up the inequality where the derivative is greater than $0$. Then I rearranged the terms to get $$k<\frac1x +x^3+x^2+3x$$

To find the maxima and minima of the right hand expression, I took the derivative and setting it equal to $0$, obtained:

$$3x^4+2x^3+3x^2-1=0$$

1. How do I factorize this?
2. How do I solve this equation(if factorizing is not the optimal way)
3. Now about the graph which I checked using an online calculator, I am getting that $f'(x)=\frac1x +x^3+x^2+3x$
   has the range $[- \infty,-3.322]\cup[3.862,\infty  ]$. If $k$ is
   always less than $f'(x)$, then doesn't that mean that $k$ ranges
   from $[-\infty, \infty]$? So $k^2$ ranges from $[0, \infty]$? But
   the answer is given $0.322^2=11.03...$. How am I interpreting the
   inequality wrong?

Comment: I didn't check your calculations, but if you factorize $x^2$ in the polynomial and solve the 2nd degree polynomial equation that Is left you obtain all the roots.

Comment: @MarcoI had made a calculation error, thanks for drawing my attention to it

Comment: Your calculations are now correct, but the polynomial doesn't have any rational root. Where did you find this exercise?

Comment: @Marco I don't happen to have the source, a friend of mine from school sent it

Comment: But @Marco what's wrong with the roots being irrational? They are still real

Comment: When dividing by $x$ to isolate $k$ in the inequality, you must consider two separate cases, $x<0$ and $x>0$.  Done correctly, this means for $x>0$ we need $k>-(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$ and for $x<0$, we need $k< -(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$.   Those extrema can be calculated numerically (the analytic expressions exist, but are practically useless due to complexity).  It doesn't lead to your answer though, max $k^2 \approx14.917...$ seems possible unless you restrict $k$ to be positive.

Comment: There Is nothing wrong, but because you already know the answer i was thinking that It is the exercise from some book of calculus. So It is strange that you have to solve the equation numerically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have $f(x) = \frac15x^5+\frac14x^4+x^3+\frac12kx^2+x$, so we need $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \quad f'(x) = x^4+x^3+3x^2+kx+1>0$.

If $x>0$, this means $k>-(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$ and for $x<0$, we need $k< -(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$.

Thus $k> - \min_{x>0}(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$ and $k<-\max_{x<0}(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$, which gives $k>-3.8623... $ and $k< 3.3222...$ numerically, hence maximum $k^2\approx (-3.8623)^2\approx 14.917.$.

Comment: Note: from $x^4+x^3+3x^2+kx+1>0$ we may conclude $k>-(x^3+x^2+3x+\frac1x)$ only when $x>0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Isn't that what is written above in the second para?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the discriminant of
$$f'(x)=x^4+x^3+3x^2+kx+1$$
which we want to be $\geq 0$, is
$$\Delta =-27k^4+50k^3+327k^2-858k+697$$
with real roots $\approx -3.8623$ and $\approx 3.3222$ with help of WolframAlpha. We need $\Delta\geq 0$. Then, all roots are real or complex. If all roots were real then
$$f'''(x)=12x^2+6x+6$$
would have two real roots which is not the case. Therefore, $$-3.8623\leq k\leq 3.3222$$
and maximum $k^2$ is $\approx (-3.8623)^2$ as Macavity found.