# Find the value(s) of $k$ for which the function $f(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^4}{4}+x^3+\frac{k}{2}x^2+x$ is increasing for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, monotone-functions

Find the value(s) of $k$ for which the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^4}{4}+x^3+\frac{k}{2}x^2+x$$
is always increasing for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My Attempt**

$f'(x)=x^4+x^3+3x^2+1+kx=\left(x^2+\frac{x}{2}+1\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}x^2+(k-1)x$

But I am not able to comprehend after this

Comment: We require $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  Try graphing this for a few values of $k$..

Comment: @GEdgar I assume he's trying to do it purely algebraically.

Comment: A quartic $ax^4 + \ldots + c$ with $a> 0$ is $\geq 0\ \forall\ x$ if either: it has one stationary point whose $y-$ coordinate is $\geq 0$ or it has two stationary points whose $y-$ coordinates are each $\geq 0. $ I reckon...

Comment: I feel like this exact question has been asked recently...

Comment: Doing these graphs will help you guess what to try to prove.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4733384/